# Python job breaks when I update the imported module's code while it is running (using pytorch dataloader) — Why?

Tags: python, pytorch, multiprocessing, python-import, pytorch-dataloader

I have code that runs for a long time (training an ML model). I have noticed that when I make edits to the .py code files (that I import) while there is a job running, the job's will sometimes break with a Syntax Error.

Through the debugging I have done, this issue seems to only occur if the updated code includes a syntax error (and if there is no syntax error, the behavior of the current jobs are not effected at all). For example, if a current job is running, and then i add a line of code like `print("debugging")`, the current job will not print anything new and will continue as is, but if i add a line of code like `print("forgot end quotation` then the currently running jobs will break with a SyntaxError. If there is such a Syntax Error, the code will continue running without breaking until new multi-processes are started (specifically, this is when pytorch dataloader workers are spawned), upon which the code will break with a Syntax Error).

The only thing i can imagine is that is has to do with the way modules are imported/reimported when a new process is started using pytorch's multiprocessing. However, this doesn't explain why I can only confirm that it occurs if a Syntax Error is introduced.

(Python 3.7.6)
(Linux OS)

Comment: Interesting. Did you try to reproduce it with some minimalistic code you could post here?

Comment: I could not reproduce this on Windows, which OS are you using? After editing the code in the imported file, it was reflected in the code which was already running as expected. Are you sure you were explicitly saving the files in both cases after editing them?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Charchit I am using a Linux OS. And yes, in both cases the files were explicitly saved.

Comment: @VPfB I have not been able to reproduce it with some minimalistic code yet. However this post i just found seems to be the same issue (with some minimalistic code): https://github.com/facebookresearch/mmf/issues/355#issuecomment-650509671

Comment: For anyone else that reaches this post with this same problem, I found this git issue that seems to explain exactly the problem I am having here (although it doesn't quite solve it): https://github.com/facebookresearch/mmf/issues/355. 

I'm not sure if I should put this in an answer to the question, or just leave it as a comment (I am new to StackOverflow).

Answer (score 1):

So, answering my own post: According to this git issue post (https://github.com/facebookresearch/mmf/issues/355), the issue is due to the new processes that are spawned for each pytorch dataloader worker (assuming workers > 0) — for each new process started, the modules are reimported. If during the reimport the code has a syntax error, it will break the current jobs (when a new process is spawned).

It seems the safest way to completely avoid the problem is to create a copy of your code for running and maintain a separate copy just for development (so that when the code is re-imported during a run/job, you can 'guarantee' that it won't have any changes). Another (likely even less practical) solution is not using any multi-processing workers).

UPDATE: other than syntax errors, also, any newly added code that lies outside of the overall if `__name__ == __main__` block or is otherwise accessed by the worker processes themselves will also change the behavior of the current runtime.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should put this response in an answer or a comment, as I am not familiar with StackOverflow. If there is a problem with my post, kindly let me know. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: That does not answer why it did not work when you added print statements, unless you put them in a position where it was never executed?